# Exception when showing an Image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, imshow

I try to show an Image with the OpenCV-function 'imshow()'.

```
 cv::Mat im = cv::imread("/home/franek/Schreibtisch/image.jpg",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
 cv::imshow("original", im);
```

Now it tells me:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9716
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9716: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

When I replace `cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` with `cv::IMREAD_COLOR`, the picture is shown and everything is fine. But I need a grayscale image.

**Edit**: the whole code:

```
cv::namedWindow("original", cv::WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED);
  cv::namedWindow("grayScale", cv::WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED);
  cv::namedWindow("cornerImage", cv::WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED);
  cv::startWindowThread();

  cv::Mat im = cv::imread("/home/franek/Schreibtisch/image.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
  cv::imshow("original", im);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/home/franek/Schreibtisch/image.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  cv::imshow("grayScale", img);
  cv::waitKey(0);
```

edit edit:
with `ldd` i found out the dependencies:

> libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2 (0x00007f2ba95d0000)
>       libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2 (0x00007f2ba8d77000)
>       libopencv_core.so.3.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.3.2 (0x00007f2ba893c000)
>       libopencv_highgui.so.4.1 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.1 (0x00007f2ba8724000)
>       libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 (0x00007f2ba7e72000)
>       libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 (0x00007f2ba557e000)
>       libopencv_core.so.4.1 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1 (0x00007f2ba429b000)

Is that the solution? The core and the highui aren't the same version...

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve], your question is off-topic without that. Anyhow, use a debugger to get a backtrace and inspect the program state to get some insight into the matter.

Comment: The error message says your error is when using `cv::cvtColor()` not `cv::imshow()`. Please post relevant code.

Comment: @ShawnMathew i know, that the Error is from `cv::cvtColor()`.
@UlrichEckhardt The StackTrace shows, that the function `cv:cvtColor()`internally calls some functions and on the TraceEnd there is the call to `cv::cvtColor()`.

What i find out is, that the Exceptions says "Hey you wanna Convert something with RGB to Grayscale, but your inputimage has only one Channel", but i don't know, why `imShow()` wants to convert the Image.

Comment: @Franek are these the only two lines of code in your application relating to `im`? If there's anything between reading the frame and displaying it, please post it.

Comment: @ShawnMathew, no there is only one Line above, where the Imview is created.

Comment: @Franek could you post those lines, along with the image. I'm unable to replicate your error. Best guess is that you have not built opencv correctly.

Comment: @ShawnMathew 
See edit.
The first Image is shown correct, but after pressing a Key the Exception occurs. I'm compiling against OpenCv 4.1.0

Comment: @Franek I'm still unable to replicate your error. could you post your image? Or rebuild opencv from source.

Comment: @ShawnMathew i think i have an idea.... (see edit)

Comment: @ShawnMathew Thank you for helping me! I found the solution. Not wrong compiling but another lib was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
the Problem was, that my Code depends in another function from `< <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>` this is a **ROS** Specific lib.
This lib uses Opencv 2.3. I head to use a fork, where someone ported this lib to OpenCV 4 [here](https://github.com/ipa-falcon/vision_opencv). Now the whole thing works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your problem if you are going to compile opencv with the correct settings:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/opencv -D \ WITH_V4L=ON BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D \ OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules ..
make -j4
```

sudo make install